# Slicing objects in Python/Django question

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to retrieve the 13 latest objects, which shows this in my shell:

```
>>> last_13_issues = Issue.objects.order_by('-id').order_by('-pub_date')[:13]
>>> print last_13_issues
[<Issue: X-Men v2 #18>, <Issue: Uncanny X-Men #543>, **<Issue: Herc #7>**, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #4>, <Issue: X-Men v2 #17>, <Issue: X-Men First Class: The High Hand #1>, <Issue: Astonishing X-Men #41>, <Issue: X-Men v2 #16>, <Issue: Generation Hope  #10>, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #3>, <Issue: Uncanny X-Men #542>, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #2>, <Issue: New Mutants v3 #28>]
```

Note Herc #7, which is marked with `** **`.

In my template, I have a slider that shows the 3 latest objects, and then the rest of the objects not in a slider. So, I did this:

```
latest_appearances = Issue.objects.order_by('-id').order_by('-pub_date')[:3]
more_latest_appearances = Issue.objects.order_by('-id').order_by('-pub_date')[4:14]
```

`latest_appearances` shows this:

```
[<Issue: X-Men v2 #18>, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #4>, <Issue: Uncanny X-Men #543>]
```

`more_latest_appearances` shows this:

```
[<Issue: X-Men v2 #17>, <Issue: X-Men First Class: The High Hand #1>, <Issue: X-Men v2 #16>, <Issue: Astonishing X-Men #41>, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #3>, <Issue: Uncanny X-Men #542>, <Issue: Generation Hope  #10>, <Issue: X-Men: Schism #2>, <Issue: New Mutants v3 #28>, <Issue: Secret Avengers #15>]
```

Notice that Herc #7 is gone. Now, since I have it ordered by `-pub_date`, 4 of the issues in `last_13_issues` have the same `pub_date`, so what can I do to fix this? I have made sure that 3 issues show the same `pub_date`, but that's obviously no help for when I have 4 issues with the same `pub_date`.

Ordering the issues only by `id` is no help either because sometimes I go back and add older issues, so sometimes issues with the highest `id` are not actually the latest issues.

**Ok, odd. Case closed. I slice in the template, instead, and it works...which is weird that it doesn't work in the views. But if anyone can figure out why, kudos to you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[3:]` instead of `[4:]` for your `more_latest_appearances`.

End index is non-inclusive for slicing:

```
>>> "abcdef"[:3]
'abc'
>>> "abcdef"[4:]
'ef'
>>> "abcdef"[3:]
'def'
```

In order to clarify things more, I'd suggest rewriting your code a little to look like this:

```
appearances = Issue.objects.order_by('-id').order_by('-pub_date')
latest_appearances = appearances[:3]
more_latest_appearances = appearances[3:14]
```

This way, you only do a single query and then split the results up, rather than doing separate queries which might return the results in differing order.

Comment: Oh, I tried that before posting this. Herc #7 is still not there. Also tried `[4:15]`. Herc #7 is still not there....

Comment: @agf - yes, which is why the text says "End index". What did you think it said? The point of the examples is to show that `[:3]` and `[3:]` is the proper pair.

Comment: So is there any reason why this is excluding issues if there are 4 or more issues with the same `pub_date` and what to do to fix this?

Comment: @Aimee See the part I just edited in at the end about rewriting your code so that it's more consistent (and efficient).

Comment: @Amber, I actually tried that as well before posting here. Still doesn't work, and Herc #7 is still not there!

Comment: Ok, odd. Case closed. I slice in the template, instead, and it works...which is weird that it doesn't work in the views.